# Executable path

Tags: c, windows

I need to find the path of where my program is running.
Using argv[0] doesn't seem to work because the program has to be run on the windows console, for example, **C:\ >player parameter1 parameter2** and I only get player on argv[0].

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you mean by "path of where my program is running" ... if you mean the current working directory, `getcwd` in c/c++ would get you what you want.

**EDIT**:
As was also mentioned, `GetModuleFileName` will retrieve the actual EXE name ... see [here](http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/app-path-in-c/11660.html) for similar question posted on another Q&A site.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Windows' [`GetModuleFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197.aspx) function to obtain the path of the executable by setting the `hModule` parameter to `NULL`.